# How to change the current database in an SQL Query window in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a SQL script that creates a new server login in the master database, and then creates a corresponding user in an existing database.

If the 'USE [database_name]' appears more than once in the query editor, it results in two errors:

> Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 USE statement is not supported to
> switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a
> different database.
>
> Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 USE
> statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new
> connection to connect to a different database.

I've considered turning on SQL CMD mode and using the :CONNECT command, but I don't want to connect to a different database server, just change the database. Connecting to a different database (or even the same one), would require me to embed a username and password in the script as well, which is not desirable.  I just want to open the SQL script connected to the right server, and be able to switch between databases.

Comment: If you’re using Azure SQL Database, you can’t switch to master to create a login. What if you want to create a login named `Frank`, and so does someone else on the same server? What if they see the login `Frank` and think it’s theirs that they already created, and change the password on you?

Comment: Aaron - what is the other way then? What if you want to run a script for all DBs in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

[Read this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/3035071/fix-error-when-you-run-a-query-that-contains-use-database-name-or-exec)

This issue occurs because Azure SQL Database does not support the "use" command.

You have to install the latest cumulative update for SQL Server

Comment: So, when the database is hosted on Azure and someone tries to use it via SSMS what update needs to be installed?
I am using SSMS v 17.9.5.

Answer (score 1):

If Azure allows you to reference Stored Procedures in other Databases using 3-part names, then you might could try executing the command using Dynamic SQL via `sp_executesql`:

```
EXEC [master].[dbo].[sp_executesql]
             N'CREATE LOGIN [Bob] WITH PASSWORD = ''fgdfgdfgdfgfd'';';
CREATE USER [Bob] FOR LOGIN [Bob];
```